# run a MySQL service before service application in Linux?

Tags: linux, mysql, ibm-unix-system-services

What are the risks that maybe I get if I run a MySQL service before service application in Linux?

```
[Unit]
Description=****
After=mysql.service
Requires=mysql.service

[Service]
ExecStart=****
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Risks?? Obviously the database must be started before an application that is using the database. If the application is started first and then the database, the application startup may fail because it won't be able to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Risks?? Obviously the database should be started before any application that will be using the database.

If the application was started before the database, the application startup might fail because it won't be able to connect to the database.

If the application starts slowly enough, and the database is small enough, then MySQL might still manage to start up before the application will actually attempt to use it, so it might still work even if started in the wrong order.

But as the database grows bigger, the MySQL start-up time might grow longer... and eventually, the start-up might start failing.